# Scroll к элементу при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, html

```
function scrollToElement(){

  let  top = document.getElementById('block-items-user').getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY - 40;
  window.scrollTo(0, top);

}

scrollToElement();
```

В браузере firefox, все работает хорошо при загрузке страницы все скролится к нужному элементу, но в webkit не работает, только если вызывать через обработчик, то есть страница сразу не скролится.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, зачем требуется `window.scrollY`, но  попробуйте вызвать с `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(function scrollToElement() {
  let top = document.getElementById('block-items-user').getBoundingClientRect().top - 40;
  window.scrollTo(0, top);
}, 100);
```

Comment: А разве там не document?